# How to get a list of Actors on a particular web socket endpoint using Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a message queue which doesn't have Actor concepts or anything so on the application startup I want to start the message queue consumer which will then keep getting messages from the queue. Now, Play framework creates an Actor for every Web Socket Connection and I want to be able to group all the Actors that hold the Web Socket connection for a particular ws endpoint so that I can broadcast all the messages that I received from message queue on particular topic to those group of Actors.

For Example the following end points will have an Actor created every time a client initiates a request to any of the end point below. so lets call them **Foo actors** and **Bar Actors**.

```
ws://localshost/foo

ws://localshost/bar
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaWebSockets

Now all I want to do is this

Pseudo code:

```
 messages = ReceiveMessagesFromQueue; // This is a live stream and it never stops.
 for message in messages:
     if message has key1:
           List<FooActors> foo_list = getAllFooActors
           broadcast(message, foo_list)
     else if message has key2:
           List<BarActors> bar_list = getAllBarActors
           broadcast(message, bar_list)
```

I am using the latest version of Play framework using Java.

Comment: Maybe [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25057854/1804173) is applicable here?

Comment: That was close. And My solution is almost 99% the same however I am trying to see if there is an effective way to maintain list of actors for every web socket endpoint. I want to broadcast message A to say actor group M and I want to broadcast message B to Actor group N.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the burden of maintaining a list of actors, but rather go for a more decoupled approach using Akka's [Event Bus](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/event-bus.html).

Doing so, you could logically group your wensocket actors per topic (foo and bar). This is loosely coupled as neither your websocket actors, nor your message queue consumer needs to know about the other side. They would simply need to subscribe or publish to a specific topic.

The code below builds on the example shown under [lookup classification](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/event-bus.html#Lookup_Classification).

When starting up, your websocket actors would just need to subscribe to the appropriate topic, roughly:

```
LookupBusImpl lookupBus = new LookupBusImpl();
lookupBus.subscribe(getSelf(), "foo"); // or "bar"
```

Your queue consumer would simply need to publish the messages to the appropriate topic, building on your pseudo code:

```
LookupBusImpl lookupBus = new LookupBusImpl();
messages = ReceiveMessagesFromQueue;
for message in messages:
  if message has key1:
    lookupBus.publish(new MsgEnvelope("foo", System.currentTimeMillis()))
 else if message has key2:
   lookupBus.publish(new MsgEnvelope("bar", System.currentTimeMillis()))
```

For a distributed version, use [Distributed Publish Subscribe in Cluster](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.17/java/distributed-pub-sub.html).